# How to split a read stream into multiple read streams by line

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules, node-streams

Hello I am a beginner in nodejs and I am trying to process large text files.
How do you split read streams to multiple read streams(by line)?

logic:

1. read aws s3 file using a read stream
2. split read stream every 10000 lines

output: multiple read streams that have a maximum of 10,000 lines

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary do you have any documentation about this?